# open websites using binary IP address

Tags: website, ip

I have curious question

Can we open websites using its binary Ip Address?

for ex :
can we open google.com (IP : 64.233.169.106) using its binary 01000000.11101001.10101001.01101010

I tried but its not working. I tried by typing http://01000000.11101001.10101001.01101010/ in the browsers address bar

Is there any way ??

Comment: The more important question here is "why??"

Comment: Some IPs can be nice enough to be used instead of domain names :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use ip address in decimal form for example (one of google ip's ) 209.85.129.99 -> 3512041827, then you can access google via http://3512041827/

Comment: Works as hex as well...

Answer (score 4):

One of the possible reasons why binary fails is that the numbers are interpreted either as decimal or octal, not binary.

Octal works in Firefox: http://0100.0351.0251.0152/ and http://0100.0351.0124552/ and so on. Hexadecimal works too.

And there can be many variations of those - one octet can be decimal, other in octal, yet another in hex. You can have a single big number, or two, or three, or four. This isn't anything browser-specific, by the way - it works everywhere in both Linux and Windows (NT). (Didn't try BSD.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to know why you want to do this!

I suppose its down to the browser - how does it interpret the address you type in? How is it supposed to know whether or not to evaluate what you've typed as a literal string or as a statement to be evaluated?

Comment: I saw a program in MTV yesterday. A professional ethical hacker Ankit Fadia was explaining this method of opening websites which are blocked by your Colleges, Offices etc. I wonder how it works. So I wanted to test how it works. I dont have any blocked websites here. But curious. Thanks

Comment: So if you saw it on MTV (a well-known, quality source of IT information), why did you need to ask here?  Wouldn't you already know the answer?

Comment: What you said may be true about MTV (a well-known, quality source of IT information). 
I am curious only because this was explained by ankit fadia, who studied at Stanford, claims to associated with CBI and FBI for national security, who wrote A guide to Ethical Hacking at age of 14,which sold million copies. 
I tried and as it's not working, I asked here.
Thanks

Comment: What are you, this bloke's publicist?

Comment: @womble:
Your 1st question was "Why ". I explained the answer.
Then you criticized for asking about something shown in MTV which is a music channel. I explained the answer.
Now an other one . I am sorry, I got work to do.

Comment: @Abhishek - i saw that episode too. The sad part is tricks broadcating on a national tv are mostly outdated. 
Also the book Faida wrote did not have much game in it 'was mostly outdated stuff. What is great is that Ankit.F could do that at the age of 14.

@womble - you are funny :)

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to enter addresses in either hex, octal, or as DWORDS, as described on [this page](http://www.pc-help.org/obscure.htm), but none of my modern browsers seem to support it any more, for any number of good reasons.

Comment: Good reason.. Hmmm, phishing?

Comment: Or anything else that obscures the URL you're about to be taken to.

Comment: You also used to be able to specify username and password for basic auth in a URL until Microsoft decided one day not to support that anymore. I swore for a lengthy period that day.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting read related to this question:

[How to Obscure Any URL](http://www.pc-help.org/obscure.htm)